# How to set 'currentNavItem' default in the view

Tags: angular-material

I know its easy to do from the model, as done here:

http://codepen.io/next1/pen/yJaojP

```
function AppCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.currentNavItem = 'page1';
  }
```

but how would you do it from the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/NRKNZQ)

Edit: In answer to your comment below you could use `ng-init`

```
<md-nav-bar md-selected-nav-item="currentNavItem" nav-bar-aria-label="navigation links" ng-init="currentNavItem='page2'">
```

However, it's worth noting in the [ngInit docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) the following:

[image]

You should be okay to use it though.

Comment: I need to create an expression in  <md-nav-bar md-selected-nav-item="currentNavItem" nav-bar-aria-label="navigation links"> that would set the currentnavitem to "page1" when nothing has yet been selected.  Basically, specify a default active page

something like md-nav-bar md-selected-nav-item="currentNavItem|'page1'", but that doesnt work

Comment: Great!   You've taught me a new directive!